# How to add special character in perl with system command?

Tags: perl, shell

I want to run this jboss cli shell command in perl script. it will work correctly If i run this command in shell terminal but it won't in inside perl script.

***In Shell:***

```
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=SAMPLE:write-attribute(name=formatter,value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n")
```

***In Perl:***

```
system("/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=SAMPLE:write-attribute(name=formatter,value=\"%d{HH:MM:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n\")");
```

The error seems to be special characters in below text.

Input : `"%d{HH:MM:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"`

Output: `%d%-5p(%t)%s%E%n`

Input : `"%d(HH:MM:ss,SSS) %-5p %c (%t) %s%E%n"`

Output: `"%d(HH:MM:ss,SSS)%-5p%c(%t)%s%E%n`

I have tried many ways to fix but i am still facing this issue.

Why `{}` and `[]` are not able to print in perl.
Could you please give me an idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run this jboss cli shell command in perl script.

Then you need to execute a jboss cli shell! Passing a jboss command (or Perl code or JavaScript code or ...) to `system` is just not going to work.

A quick google search seems to indicate it's named `jboss-cli.sh` and it accepts the standard `-c COMMAND` argument, so

```
my $cmd = '/subsystem=logging/...';
system('jboss-cli.sh', '-c', $cmd);
```

Comment: Might I recommend not using the system() function? 

There are much better and safer options to make an external call to another application

Comment: @falconspy, You might, but I don't know why you would do that. I also don't know why you think there's something safer.